# What is the vm.overcommit_ratio in Linux?

Tags: linux, unix, virtual-memory

Here is my current setting:

```
vm.overcommit_ratio = 50 (default)
vm.overcommit_memory = 2
```

And Current Memory Usage:

```
[localhost~]$ free -g
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:            47         46          0          0          0         45
-/+ buffers/cache:          1         45
Swap:           47          0         47
```

As per the [documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/4/html/Reference_Guide/s3-proc-sys-vm.html) what I understood is:

`vm.overcommit_memory = 2` will not allow to overcommit memory than 50 % of RAM `(as vm.overcommit_ratio is 50)` but still I can see that current memory usage is 46 GB out of 47 GB.

Did I misunderstood anything?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Question answered on superuser : https://superuser.com/questions/1184087/overcommit-memory-and-overcommit-ratio

Comment: @jww Memory allocation is absolutely relevant to programming and development. https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting That said, I agree "Did I misunderstood?" is not a real question.

Comment: @DavidParks Well, I changed the question slighty. I ended up here because I wanted to understand why my vm.overcommit_ratio = 50 :-) Also I think it's a bad idea to copy a non-question to SuperUser. Better to fix the question before moving/copying it somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the default for vm.overcommit_memory is 0 and not 2. Is the overcommit_ratio only relevant to mode 2? I assume yes, but I'm not entirely sure.

From https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/vm/overcommit-accounting

> 0 -   Heuristic overcommit handling. Obvious overcommits of       address
> space are refused. Used for a typical system. It      ensures a seriously
> wild allocation fails while allowing      overcommit to reduce swap
> usage.  root is allowed to        allocate slightly more memory in this
> mode. This is the         default.
>
> 1 -   Always overcommit. Appropriate for some scientific      applications.
> Classic example is code using sparse arrays       and just relying on the
> virtual memory consisting almost      entirely of zero pages.
>
> 2 -   Don't overcommit. The total address space commit        for the system
> is not permitted to exceed swap + a       configurable amount (default is
> 50%) of physical RAM.         Depending on the amount you use, in most
> situations        this means a process will not be killed while accessing
> pages but will receive errors on memory allocation as       appropriate.

Instead of `free -g` which I assume rounds down to zero, you might want to use `free -m` or just `free` to be more precise.

This might be interesting as well:

`cat /proc/meminfo|grep Commit`